# img-wrapper doesn't display png

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My code displays jpg images but not png. How to make img-wrapper display png files? In my example the first image in the array is jpg while the second is png. But I see only the title of the image for png file. Thanks.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view_topic.css">
</head>

<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="outerdiv"></div>
<script>

$(this).css('height',"100px");

var get_a_image = ["http://iancaple.ru/upload/images/20200804_225812.jpg", "http://iancaple.ru/upload/images/313.png"];
var counter = 1;
var ready_cnt = 0;

 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#outerdiv').append(
    $('<div>').prop({
        id: 'myDiv1',
        //innerHTML: 'Hi there!',
        className: 'img-wrapper'
    })
);

$('#outerdiv').append(
    $('<div>').prop({
        id: 'myDiv2',
        //innerHTML: 'Hi there!',
        className: 'img-wrapper'
    })
);

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $('#myDiv' + (ready_cnt + 1)).append($('<img id="theImg2">').attr({
        'src': get_a_image[ready_cnt], //'https://' + imgUrl ,
        'alt': 'test image ' + ready_cnt + 1
    })).scrollTop(9999)
    console.log("get_a_image[" + ready_cnt + "]=" + get_a_image[ready_cnt]);
    console.log('#myDiv' + (ready_cnt + 1));
    ready_cnt++;
}
```

});

Comment: The HTML ImageElement doesn't have a problem with png files. Are you aware that your url `http://iancaple.ru/upload/images/313.png` points to nowhere?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the broken link `http://iancaple.ru/upload/images/313.png` . Pasting this link browser doesn't show any image. Please make sure the link is accessible.

the first link is working fine and therefore the image is also displayed.

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Yes link is broken. Filename is space313.png

Comment: can you please accept my answer? or do you need further help

Comment: Thank you. First problem is solved. But now I need to save the user adjusted size of div with img-wrapper. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: you can get the size of window using `var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight`